# how to disable alternative tokens in C++

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm building [micropython](https://github.com/micropython/micropython) which is meant to be compiled as C-code; my project team wants it compiled as C++ code so we don't have to mix C and C++ code.

Ok no big deal except [**parse.c**](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/a3dc1b1957d2c96d7c60c2c629c95077b03488a1/py/parse.c#L87) contains

[`#define or(n)                   (RULE_ACT_OR | n)`](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/a3dc1b1957d2c96d7c60c2c629c95077b03488a1/py/parse.c#L87)

And the C++ compiler says

> error : "or" cannot be used as a macro name as it is an operator in C++

I definitely don't want to start messing with the micropython source.

**QUESTION**

Is there a C++  gcc compiler option to undefine one (or all) the [alternative tokens](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative)?

Comment: **TL;DR**: `-fno-operator-names`

Comment: Is it very clever to redefine existing definitions...?

Comment: @Klaus I want to modify it as little as possible to make integration with future micropython releases easier.